# Returning copy of data.table from ReferenceClass method

Tags: r, data.table, reference-class

I try to return copies of `data.table`s from methods of a ReferenceClass:

```
dummy <- setRefClass(
  "dummy",
  fields = list(
    dt = "data.table"
  ),
  methods = list(
    initialize = function( df ){
      if( !missing( df ) ){
        dt <<- data.table( df , key = "a" )
      }
    },
    getTab = function( ix ){
      return( copy(dt[ ix, ]) )
    }
  )
)
```

However, calling `dummy$getTab()` yields an error which I don't understand:

```
d <- dummy$new( data.frame( a = 1:10, b = 1:10 ) )
d$getTab( 2:5 )

Error in if (shallow) assign(field, get(field, envir = selfEnv), envir = vEnv) else { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (shallow) assign(field, get(field, envir = selfEnv), envir = vEnv) else { :
 the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I have no clue, what it means and where this comes from. Plus, the following two procedures work without any problems:

```
copy( d$dt[ 2:5 ] )

mycopy <- function( dt, ix ) {
  return( copy(dt[ ix, ]) )
}
mycopy( d$dt, 2:5 )
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok sorry, this was a dumb error, I simply had overseen the method `envRefClass$copy()`. So the solution is to call `data.table::copy` explicitly:

```
dummy <- setRefClass(
  "dummy",
  fields = list(
    dt = "data.table"
  ),
  methods = list(
    initialize = function( df ){
      if( !missing( df ) ){
        dt <<- data.table( df , key = "a" )
      }
    },
    getTab = function( ix ){
      return( data.table::copy(dt[ ix, ]) )
    }
  )
)
```